# How to aggregate sum in sqlite Xamarin to get a total count?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, sqlite

I have a feature class which contain property information, what I would like to do it total the value of all properties and display that in a table. The attribute table looks something like this:

```
           ObjectId          PID     Value
             0              1000    10,000
             1              1001    25,000
             2              1002   100,000
```

I would like to sum the value field, in order to give me a total for the entire area. So in this example, the value of all properties would be $135,000... I would like to calculate this and display it...

sounds like a pretty straight forward problem, but I can't seem to find a solution. How to do this on Xamarin forms MVVM format

Comment: You left out all the important stuff, like everything... and your code

Comment: put yourself in someone else's shoes. read your question like someone who cannot see your code and ask yourself this : "do i have all the information to be able to answer this question"?

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you are using SQL then you would use something like:

```
select sum(count) from TableXXX where location = 'colombo'.
```

If you are using EF then it would be more like:

```
double x = dbContext.DbSet("XXX")
    .Where(item => item.Location == "colombo")
    .Select(item => item.Count)
    .Sum();
```

Comment: Note that you can pass a delegate into [`Sum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Sum__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Single__), so your last two lines would be `.Sum(item => item.Count);`.